# Regex in Swift not working when escaping backslashes

Tags: regex, string, cocoa, swift, nsregularexpression

I have a regex that I'm trying to use in Swift to parse out the color values of a string in the form of "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"

My regex string is this:

`^rgba?\(\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\%?)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\%?)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\%?)\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)$`

You can see it working here:

[image: cl.ly/XxuH]

When I escape the backslashes and attempt to use it with `NSRegularExpression` it no longer matches the given string.

`^rgba?\\(\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*(?:\\s*,\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s*)?\\)$`

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Code Example:

```
import Foundation

var pattern = "^rgba?\\(\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*(?:\\s*,\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s*)?\\)$"

var string = "rgba(255, 234, 243, 1)"

var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(0), error: nil)

regex.numberOfMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(string))) // Yields 1. Should yield 4
```

Comment: Why is question is tagged with Objective-C when the question is about Swift? – A small self-contained code example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @MartinR because it's using NSRegularExpression and regexes in Swift vs. Obj-c are one to one.

Comment: The common factor is the Cocoa (Touch) framework; the ObjC _language_ has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @MartinR code example added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numberOfMatchesInString` returns 1 because the entire pattern matches once.
Use `rangeAtIndex()` to get the ranges matched by the capture groups:

```
let pattern = "^rgba?\\(\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d+)?\\%?)\\s*(?:\\s*,\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s*)?\\)$"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)

let rgba : NSString = "rgba(255, 234, 243, 1)"
if let match = regex!.firstMatchInString(rgba, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, rgba.length)) {
    println(rgba.substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(1)))
    println(rgba.substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(2)))
    println(rgba.substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(3)))
    println(rgba.substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(4)))
}
```

Output:

```
255
234
243
1
```

---

**Update:** Using the [`Regex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex) type that was introduced with Swift 5.7, requires macOS 13+ or iOS 16+):

```
let rgba = "rgba(255, 234, 243, 1)"

let pattern = /rgba?\(\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\%?)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\%?)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\%?)\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\)/

if let match = try? pattern.wholeMatch(in: rgba) {
    print(match.1)
    print(match.2)
    print(match.3)
    print(match.4)
}
```